# RESTful Webservice

Tags: rest, http, web, service

as it's already stated in the title, I am looking for an answer concering Restful Webservices. The problem I have is that multiple sources (xml, images) are supposed to be POSTed in a single request/response simultaniously. Does anyone have a "buzz word" or something related that I could start with? Thanks in advance. (via HTTP /-s)

Comment: You don't really want to POST multiple sources of data with one request, use multiple requests. And this kind of questions is off-topic on Stackoverflow anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're perhaps looking for is [Multipart Messages](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html).

In short, it's a Mime-Type, that let's you create a message composed of multiple messages with potentially different types.